# Search PDF files with more than 100 pages and moving them into directory in UNIX/LINUX terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, find, pdf, search

I'm trying to search for PDF files that have more than 100 pages and then moving them into a specific directory in the UNIX/LINUX terminal. Something a bit like this:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -pagenumber>100 -exec mv -t ~/directory
```

Obviously `-pagenumber>100` is not the right command. Is there a specific command for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difficult bit here is to count the number of pages in a PDF document.

The `find` utility can't do this by itself, so we need an external tool to do this.

On most Unix systems, you will be able to install `exiftool`.  This tool is part of the `libimage-exiftool-perl` package on Ubuntu, and of `p5-Image-ExifTool` on OpenBSD.  It is able to do many things related to meta data in media files, for example to output the number of pages in a PDF document:

```bsh
$ exiftool -s3 -PageCount document.pdf
10
```

We can use this with `find` to move the documents with more than 100 pages to a separate directory:

```bsh
mkdir -p ~/tmp/100-plus-pages || exit

find . -name '*.pdf' -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if [ "$(exiftool -s3 -PageCount "$pathname")" -gt 100 ]; then
            mv "$pathname" ~/tmp/100-plus-pages
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

This calls a short in-line script for batches of found PDF files.  The in-line script iterates over the current batch of found files and runs the `exiftool` command on each.  If the number outputted by the command is strictly greater than 100, the file is moved to the `100-plus-pages` directory in `~/tmp`.

We want to avoid searching the destination directory for PDF files, which is why I chose to create that directory under `~/tmp` (anywhere separate from where `find` will search would do, but you probably want it to be on the same filesystem).  You could also do as follows to avoid entering the directory if you want to keep it in the current directory:

```bsh
mkdir -p 100-plus-pages || exit

find . -path ./100-plus-pages -prune -o -name '*.pdf' -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if [ "$(exiftool -s3 -PageCount "$pathname")" -gt 100 ]; then
            mv "$pathname" 100-plus-pages
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

You may want to test run this with `mv` replaced by `echo` first.

Comment: `/tmp` is often on a separate filesystem from `/home` (often tmpfs), and you wouldn't actually want to copy the files to tmpfs and then back.  As you say, any directory on the same FS that is outside the path find will search, or that you exclude, will work.  Or write a list of filename to a file (in /tmp) and read it back later, possibly 0-terminated for reading with `xargs -0` if you can get a shell to emit a 0 byte.  (`printf` and `echo` builtins won't in bash.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, I chose `/tmp` _only_ because it would be away from where `find` would probably look. I've changed it to `~/tmp`in the answer and added a note. The main point is to avoid looking at files in the destination directory.

Comment: Putting /tmp in a separate filesystem has become less common for most distros. Unless you want to put it in RAM to minimize write actions on an SSD. /tmp is very nice for temporary storage as it is cleaned up at reboot. If you are like me, I always forget to clean out tmp folders.

Comment: The discussion about `/tmp` being on a different filesystem or not distracts from the actual question and answer. I will not address that particular issue further as it is irrelevant to the issue at hand. If it interests you enough to leave further comments, then please consider asking about it in a separate question, or open a chat to discuss it.

Comment: You could `find . -name 100-plus-pages -prune -o -name '*.pdf' -exec ...`. Reread `man find`.

Comment: @waltinator That would avoid all directories with that name, not just the one under `.`. I did read the manual. See also the last code block in my answer. I wanted to give a simpler variant of the command, and then the one with `-prune` (which may not be necessary in whatever situation the user in the question is). I don't know why people seems so hung up about this thing with wherever we're writing the files.

Answer (score 6):

You can run Pdfinfo (in Debian systems, from `poppler-utils` package) on each PDF file, pipe it to Awk to look for the `Pages:` line, and exit with zero (success) only if that page count is greater than 100:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c '
  pdfinfo "$1" | awk "/^Pages:/{exit !(\$2>100)}"
' _ {} \; -exec mv {} ~/dir \;
```

Note we had to escape `\$2` because the Awk script is inside double-quotes and the shell would expand `$2` to a positional argument.

`awk` evaluates the logical expression `(\$2>100)` and returns `1` it it is true, while shells and `find` use `0` for true, hence it needs to be inverted for the proper exit code => `!(\$2>100)`. So always take this opposing definition of true and false between `awk` and shells into account, when combining the two.

Pdftk may also be used in a similar fashion: `pdftk "$1" dump_data`; See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14736593) for more ways to count pages in a PDF file.